# Use Differentiability of Power Series to find the sum $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I found the following values after differentiating:

$$
(x+1)^n, n(x+1)^{n-1}, n(n-1)(x+1)^{n-2} 
$$

It looks a lot like the Sum for $F(x)= 1/(1-x)$, but i'm not sure where to proceed from here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With differentiating of 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
we have
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}(x+1)^n=\dfrac{1}{1-(x+1)}=-\dfrac1x$$
valid for $|x+1|<1$, then with integration of both sides
$$f(x)=\int_{-1}^x\dfrac{1}{-t}\ dt=-\ln(-x)$$

Comment: Since I found the radius of convergence to be [-2, 0), would I then plug in (-2) such as f(x) = -ln(-(-2)) = -ln(2) ?

Comment: Of course, it is.